# Consumo WS Rest retorna nulo

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Estou consumindo um WS para obter dados de veículos, a API que me foi passada retorna um JSON:

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "",
"result": [  {
        "Codigo": "1013",
        "Placa": "ABC1234",
        "Ano": 2016,
        "Uf": "SP",
        "Marca": "Marca1",
        "Modelo": "OF-1418"
    }, {
        "Codigo": "1015",
        "Placa": "ABC1244",
        "Ano": 2016,
        "Uf": "SP",
        "Marca": "Marca1",
        "Modelo": "OF-1418"
    }, {
        "Codigo": "100",
        "Placa": "KYX2244",
        "Ano": 2013,
        "Uf": "SP",
        "Marca": "Mbb",
        "Modelo": "OF-1313"
    }
  ]
}
```

Eu estou usando `restTemplate` do Spring e para já transformar o JSON em objeto analisei o JSON e criei três classes:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Result {

   private String codigo;
   private String placa;    
   private Integer ano; 
   private String uf;   
   private String marca;    
   private String modelo;   


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RestResponse {

   private Boolean success;
   private String message;
   private Result[] result;


public class Response {

   @JsonProperty
   private RestResponse RestResponse;
```

E para consumir em minha classe de serviço fiz desta forma:

```
    Response response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Response.class);

    System.out.println("Retorno: " + response.toString());
```

Só que o retorno é nulo.

Onde eu estou errando?

**Atualizacao do codigo**

Eliminei a classe Response, fiquei apenas com duas classes a RestResponse e a Result agora percebo que algo já mudou estou chamando assim

```
RestResponse response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, RestResponse.class);
```

ao observar o objeto response o atributo sucess e message agora tem conteúdo porém o atributo Result[] result eu verifico ele

```
Result[] array = response.getResult();
System.out.println("Tamanho do array: " + array.length);
```

e o array tem tamanho mais qdo itero sobre ele os atributos estão nulos.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz duas alterações a primeira eu implementei Serializable e segundo o JSON o par chave/valor a chave ele começa com Maiúscula então eu inseri @JsonProperty para cada atributo 
@JsonProperty("Codigo") private String codigo;
@JsonProperty("Placa") private String placa;
.......